# JavaFX - Dynamically increase the height of StackPane based on children height

Tags: javafx-2

I have a GridPane which contains a `StackPane` at `(1,0)`. To this `StackPane` I'll dynamically include other `Pane`s based on some logic. I want this `StackPane` to automatically 
increase the height based on the height of the Pane that is included.

```
stackPane.heightProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>(){
    @Override
    public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number oldVal, Number newVal ){
        stackPane.setPrefHeight( newVal.doubleValue() + 230 );
    }

} );
```

This method gets called after I add the `Pane` to the `stackPane`. But on the screen it doesn't show the new height. Could this be because of the `GridPane`'s row height?
For that column (where the stackPane is included), I've set the `maxHeight` to `MAX_VALUE` and `prefHeight` to `USE_COMPUTED_VALUE`

Comment: Normally a `gridpane`'s row should allow auto-increment of height, depending on its content. If you doubt it is because of the GridPane, you may try using [`RowConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html)

Comment: the VGrow is set to "ALWAYS". But still it doesn't grow automatically.